# How to model terminal velocity as a function of gravitational acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, calculus

Taking the most simplistic form of terminal velocity, $v=\sqrt{\frac{mg}{c}}$

I want to try and derive an equation that models the velocity as g changes in height.. Because obviously the terminal velocity high up near the ISS is different than at sea level..

To begin I started with:

$$v^2=\frac{m}{c}dg$$

Then I had to put dg in terms of height:

$$g=\frac{GM_E}{r^2}$$

$$dg=\frac{-2GM_E}{r^3} \space dr$$

Now I can do the integration:

$$v^2=\frac{-2GM_Em}{c}\int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{1}{r^3} \space dr$$

which gives me:

$$v=\sqrt{\frac{-GM_Em}{c} \space (\frac{1}{{r_1}^2}-\frac{1}{{r_2}^2)}}$$

Now if you solve this with some reasonable values, remembering that the r values are the radius of the earth + your height.. I am not sure if what I derived makes sense..

If I solve this I get very large numbers... can someone please correct my mental thinking in this and visualizing what I just derived?

Comment: A couple points: 1: Your second equation should be$$\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}r}=-\frac{2GM_E}{r^3}$$thus leading to your third equation. 2. Never write an equation with $\mathrm{d}\text{something}$ on only one side. I would insert an integral in the first equation, and carry it through the next one. 3. Assuming$$c^{-1}=\frac{2}{\rho AC_d}$$be aware that $\rho$ will change with $r$.

Comment: Thank you for those edits. I know $\rho$ will change with r, but I am taking baby steps first before tackling that! Either way, I know the integration is correct, but the answers I get from them just don't make sense? Is it because since I am taking the derivation that it is the sums of all the terminal velocities from r1 to r2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this is done correctly.  There is no integration required at all.  The "equilibrium" force balance on the falling object is simply $cv^2=mg(r)$.  So, if g is treated as a function of r,  the "terminal velocity" varies with r, and the local value of r should be used in the equation $v(r)=\sqrt{\frac{mg(r)}{c}}$.  But, how can we call it a terminal velocity if it is increasing as r decreases?  Well, to be strictly Kosher, it's not.  But if the drag is high enough, then the transition to this velocity at the highest altitudes will be rapid, and this equation will then give a good approximation to the velocity at all altitudes below (provided the air density effect is also included). But, to be strictly correct, there is no terminal velocity if g varies with r.  If we want to get more accurate, we can also include the ma term in the force balance, and integrate that with respect to r, but that solution also will not result in a constant terminal velocity.

Comment: So simply... There isn't a way to model this?

Comment: This is the model.  It can give a pretty accurate estimate of the velocity as it slowly changes during the fall, but the velocity does change.